# What's the difference between 'cutlery', 'silverware' and 'crockery'?

Tags: word-choice, differences, nouns

What's the difference between 'cutlery', 'silverware' and 'crockery'? Are there any differences between them?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*[Cutlery](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/cutlery)* has two definitions: 1. cutting/edged implements used for serving or eating food; 2. eating utensils in general. Without further context, an American is likely to assume the first definition (knives), while a Brit is more likely to go for the generic meaning. *[Silverware](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/silverware)* also means eating utensils, especially silver-colored ones, though nowadays, most silverware is not actually made of silver. An American synonym that does not imply anything about the silver content (or lack thereof) is *[flatware](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/flatware)*.

*[Crockery](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/crockery)* is completely different: in British English usage, it means the things on the dinner table that are usually made of china or porcelain -- plates, bowls, saucers, cups, serving bowls, etc. In American English, *crockery* is used for certain earthenware cooking pots, but given enough context, an American would probably understand *crockery* used according to the British definition.

Comment: As an American, I understand crockery in the British sense, although my first thought would be ceramic instead of china or porcelain. :) That might just be my family, though...

Comment: Lovely rundown of the distinctions!  One extra thing I’d add: “silverware” in the general sense is, I think, less common in the UK than in the US — when I first moved to the States I found “plastic silverware” jarring, though it was clear what it meant.

Comment: Excellent answer, good that British/American meanings were clearly defined - as they differ a lot around cooking and food.  I agree with PLL on the *silverware* word, in the UK we use that pretty much exclusively for actual silver.  Note that it is not limited to cutlery either, *silverware* is used to refer to any item not purely decorative that is made of silver; a candelabra for instance.  Stainless steel cutlery would definitely not be classed as *silverware* here.

Comment: @Orbling: strange how each dialect is flexible on one word, but not on the other. An American has no problem expanding "silverware" to eating utensils of all materials, but wants to take the "cut" in "cutlery" literally; while a Brit has no problem expanding "cutlery" to include all eating utensils, but wants to take the "silver" in "silverware" literally.

Comment: @Martha: The differences between the two languages are quite extensive in certain domains.  Particularly I find when the domain is to do with home life, cooking and food are possibly the least similar areas of the language.

Comment: @Claudiu: With regard to your expletive phrase, I've never heard it with the "bull" prefix, certainly regarded as US-only; but well known in the UK due to television influence.

Comment: @Rhodri, in the US, "Crock Pot" is a particular brand of slow cooker.

Comment: I was once in a restaurant in the US and, for some reason, didn't have a knife or fork - so, being unaware of the variation in usage, I asked for "cutlery", to be met by a blank stare from the girl serving our table! I was then perplexed (again, unaware of the regional variations) to be told "Oh, you mean 'silverware'!", when I would have been quite happy with stainless steel. It is occasionally very surprising how two native speakers of nominally the same language can fail to communicate about everyday matters :-)

Comment: As an American, I understand "cutlery" to refer to any eating utensils, not just knives. Though it is much more common to say "silverware" -- as you say, regardless of whether it is silver, aluminum, or plastic. "Utensils" is also fairly common as a general term.

Comment: Hmmm?  I don't understand @Martha's distinction between 1 and 2.  What are examples of eating utensils that aren't used for eating and serving food?  Do you mean cutlery sometimes is pots and pans??  Help me out here.

Comment: @Merk: notice the "cutting/edged" part of #1. To most Americans, "cutlery" == knives, and knives only. Forks and spoons are silverware, not cutlery.

Answer (score 9):

I've always heard, and used, the terms thus: Cutlery only describes knives. Silverware (or simply "silver" here in the South), means eating utensils, regardless of their material (it's perfectly acceptable to refer to "plastic silverware," like what you would get with a to-go order from a restaurant). Crockery isn't really used in the US, to my knowledge. I know this word from my reading of books by British authors, but I don't know that I've ever heard it in the US. My understanding is that crockery would only mean plates, bowls and cups used at the table.

Comment: Interesting to learn the colloquial uses in the South.  The usage of *silverware* is odd to include any substance.

Comment: "Plastic silverware" is actually [plasticware](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plasticware).

Answer (score 1):

I polled my friends for what they call 'knives forks and spoons as a group'. Respondants were mostly US, with a few international. This was the result:

[image]

Silverware is the favorite term, followed by utensils, cutlery then flatware.

No one mentioned crockery as it doesn't reference the members of the silverware family.