# Where is the word "cutlery" in common usage

Tags: differences, american-english, british-english

During a trip to the US I realised that many Americans have never heard the word cutlery before ... however some have. Where in the English speaking world (and in particular where in the US) is this is a common term for knives, forks and spoons?

Comment: It is perhaps not the most commonly spoken-of thing in the world, so it’s hard to judge with any kind of precision; but I don’t recall ever meeting a native speaker, American or otherwise, who did _not_ know what cutlery is. It’s a perfectly normal, though perhaps not overly common, word to me in all varieties of English.

Comment: Ah well I certainly have met Americans who didn't know.  In British English it is the standard term and so I would guess that it is in standard usage in many former colonies too... maybe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between 'cutlery', 'silverware' and 'crockery'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6339/whats-the-difference-between-cutlery-silverware-and-crockery)

Comment: @FumbleFingers My question is really a geographical one that is not covered in that other question. I suspect that one could draw a map that would contain the answer.

Comment: @ Anush: I don't know why you say that. The accepted (and highly-upvoted) answer (and comments) on that one repeatedly make the point about a US/UK difference. In fact, although the OP there might have thought he was going to be given a *semantic* difference, practically all the responses are concerned with the *regional* difference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I mean geographically within the US (or by country outside of the US). Within the US I suspect it varies by state and maybe also by major city.

Comment: @ Anush: Well, as yet, no-one agrees with my closevote. But I think all you're going to get is people saying *"I live in this State/city, and I do/don't adopt the BrE usage"*. You'd have to survey individuals in detail, because just looking at "frequency of occurrence" in regionally-locatable tweets, for example, wouldn't take account of the US *cutlery = **knives** and nothing else* interpretation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The answers may be poor but they don't have to be. It's not impossible that there are reliable sources for this question.

Comment: Hmmm. ELU (and SO in general) don't really like "poll-type" questions.

Comment: @anush re your guess about former colonies: here in the colony of Victoria (now part of Australia) cutlery is common, except in my home where we say "cutlery and forklery" as a joke.

Answer (score 2):

Macmillan flags *[cutlery](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/cutlery)* as "mainly British," and goes on to note that the usual American word is *[silverware](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/silverware)*. (Which apparently has other connotations in British English.)

Another chiefly American synonym is *[flatware](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/flatware)*.

Comment: What do Americans call cutlery that is not silver?

Comment: I am not sure it is the same in every state in the US.

Comment: @Tristanr Plastic silverware?

Comment: WS2, that's a good guess but, doesn't cover cutlery made of other materials.

Comment: @Tristan: Americans call spoons, forks, and knives *silverware*, no matter what they're made of. What do Brits call cutlery which can't be used to cut anything?

Comment: @PeterShor The most common British usage for cutlery just refers to implements used for eating, such as knives, forks and spoons. I suppose the use of (table) forks and spoons for eating post-dates the cutler.

Comment: Peter Shor, that is still called *cutlery*.

Comment: Canadians also use _cutlery_.

Answer (score 2):

In the United States, *[cutlery](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=cutlery)* is a formal (read: pretentious) word for cutting and peeling implements, that is, knives and paring utensils. I am primarily familiar with it from department store signs, and perhaps the decline of department store shopping contributes to its declining usage, like calling bed and bath goods *domestics*.

*Cutlery* in the British sense encompasses all eating and serving utensils, for which most Americans would say *[silverware](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=silverware)* or *[flatware](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=flatware)*, regardless of shape or material. This usage of *silverware* sets it apart from other types of *-ware* which refer to the material (e.g. *glassware*, *plasticware*) or the use of the item (e.g. *housewares*, *giftware*).

Martha Stewart calls it flatware, and that is good enough for me.

Comment: Spoons really aren't flat :)

Comment: @Anush Spoons really don't cut either :).

Comment: @choster True; most Americans are exposed to the term _cutlery_ only when they're shopping for wedding presents...

Comment: @choster :) I think the addition of spoons and forks to the list of cutlery was as a result of domestic eating habits eating changing.

Comment: Unless the English were still eating their food only with knives in 1893, I doubt this very much. The OED says the word *cutlery* was last updated in 1893, and it does not seem to include any non-sharp implements.

Comment: @PeterShor The OED entry does indeed look very out of date (this is not uncommon for the OED).  My British Collins dictionary gives exactly the definition I gave you before.  I can assure you the Collins definition is also the correct contemporary one. The point of my comment was to suggest how the meaning may have drifted from its original one of only referring to cutting implements. I think the table fork came to Britain in the 17th century but I don't know when the word cutlery was updated first to include it.

Comment: This brings up the question: what did English-speaking people call eating utensils like forks and spoons before around 1850? Looking in Google books, the word *cutlery* seems to have been restricted to knives and other tools with blades, and [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=silverware%2C+tableware%2C+flatware&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csilverware%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctableware%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflatware%3B%2Cc0) shows Americans weren't using any of the obvious words, either.

Comment: @PeterShor http://cutleryorigins.webs.com/ is reasonably informative and plausible on this front. "The first forks were actually imported from Italy, and they became more mass produced in the 19th century, when every household would start to get them to use as part of their everyday routine. "  .. "Spoons were the latest piece of cutlery to hit the UK. Although they had been around since early civilisation, in northern Europe they had been made out of wood for many years. They finally became more used in England in the 19th century, when drinking soup became seen as more rude."

Comment: Here's [a link - which took no time or effort to find - to "plastic cutlery"](http://www.amazon.com/Crystal-Clear-Cutlery-Pieces-Forks/dp/B001UBLVCY/).  Kirkland is the Costco house brand; I don't see how you can call this "pretentious".  Here's [a link to "Looks Like Silver" disposable flatware](http://www.amazon.com/Reflections-Heavyweight-Silver-Disposable-Flatware/dp/B000JHGQKW), which arguably **is** pretentious.

Comment: @PeterShor http://bit.ly/1i8ATUd is rather nice.  If you search Google books for "table cutlery" in the 19th century you get quite a few similar adverts.  I feel that before that the concept just wasn't common.

Comment: @Anush: [This advertisement](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pRJEAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA327&dq=%22table+cutlery%22+spoons&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6CzoUpPWIOmusATqhIGwBQ&ved=0CEEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22table%20cutlery%22%20spoons&f=false), from 1861, quite clearly lists table knives, dessert knives, and  carvers in the *"celebrated table cutlery"* category, and spoons and forks in the *"electroplated spoons and forks"* category.

Comment: @PeterShor  Yes you are right.  So the term must have acquired its current usage more recently. It also indicates how they referred to spoons and forks before the current usage of the term cutlery.

Comment: @PeterShor I posted a separate question about the first use of cutlery in its modern meaning.  I suspect now it might be very recent.

Comment: @Anush You're making quite an assumption on the basis of one usage in one advert. Very often, manufacturers and distributers follow their own styles. This is certainly true in the field of (especially Victorian say) furniture, where similar pieces are often invested with different grandiose terms (eg chiffonier / cupboard / chest of drawers / buffet).